# Pass collectionview from function to Selector (UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

So I am using a function that a user can do a long press on a `UICollectionView` (note: I have multiple collection views on my screen). This triggers an action, but when I try to pass the collection view from my `longPressFolder` function to the `handleLongPress` function, it doesn't work.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()       

        // add long press to collection View
        longPressFolder(newestFoldersCollectionView)
        longPressFolder(topFoldersCollectionView)
}

   func longPressFolder(collectionview: UICollectionView) {
        // Long press
        let lpgr : UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FolderOverviewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
        lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.4
        lpgr.delegate = self
        lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        collectionview.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
    }
```

This is the part where the code doesn't work. It says that my collection view is unresolved, but I can't seem to find a way to pass the collection view from my one function to the other.

```
// long press
func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
        return
    }

    let p = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(collectionview)

    if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = (collectionview.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p))!{
        //do whatever you need to do
        ...               
        }
        collectionview.reloadData()
    }        
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass a view to `locationInView()`. Where's it getting the `collectionview` variable in your `handleLongPress` function?

Comment: @shim it isn't at the moment, the issue is that I can't seem to pass my collectionView to the handleLongPress function

Comment: You can get a reference to a gesture recognizer's view if you use `.view` on the recognizer. So try `let collectionview = gestureRecognizer.view as! UICollectionView`

Comment: Hmmm, if I try this, and press the second cell in my second collectionview, it selects the second cell in my first collectionview.. but at least it's progress :) I'll update the code, so you can check if I'm doing anything incorrect.

Comment: @shim please make an answer of your solution, i'll mark it as correct. Was being stupid with the selection of the collectionview ^^

Comment: OK, but now does your edited code in your question work properly? Might be confusing for anyone else reading this question.

Comment: works properly with your line of code added to it. Deleted it in my question, since it might indeed confuse people if I let it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to a gesture recognizer's view if you use `.view` on the recognizer. So try:

```
let collectionview = gestureRecognizer.view as! UICollectionView
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = (collectionview.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p))!{
```

with

```
if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = ((gestureRecognizer.view as! UICollectionView).indexPathForItemAtPoint(p))!{
```

Comment: didn't fix my issue. Updated my code to a newer version, which works, but only for the first collectionview. Even if I press on the second one.

Comment: do you have `collectionview` variable declared outside `longPressFolder` or `handleLongPress`?

Comment: and your collectionViews didn't overlay one another?

Comment: try also add gesture recognizer only to second collection view and look, does it work